Win32 ISO C API to query the optimum block size on a SMB filesystem?
Is there a public Win32 ISO C API to query the optimum read/write block size for a SMB filesystem?
I'm asking because SMB is a network filesystem, and on the server side the block size depends on the filesystem which is being exported to the client, and therefore varies between each mounted filesystem on the client side.

SMB is a network filesystem not really, smb is protocol to access resources, they can be files or printers or many other things, also even if it is file share - server does not have to store it on disk, it could be in memory

OK, then narrow this down to files exported via SMB, please.
